# Give a new class by ng-class with variable value

Tags: css, angularjs, ng-class

Hi I've got follow code:

```js
angular.module("myApp", []).controller("myController", function($scope) {
  $scope.fieldSize = "cInputLarge"; //Change for the effect to -> cInputMedium, cInputLarge
});
```

```css
.cDefault {
  width: 50px;
}
.cInputMedium {
  width: 100px;
}
.cInputLarge {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <input class="cDefault" ng-class="{{fieldSize}}">
  <br>
  <br>{{fieldSize}}
</div>
```

My goal is, to give to the input a class name, which changes the width of it. I know how ng-class works with conditions, but is something like this also possible (to give a class name in the ng-class and it takes it's properties)?

Thanks and cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the name of the variable, it should be sufficient:

```js
angular.module("myApp", []).controller("myController", function($scope) {
  $scope.fieldSize = "cInputLarge"; //Change for the effect to -> cInputMedium, cInputLarge
});
```

```css
.cDefault {
  width: 50px;
}
.cInputMedium {
  width: 100px;
}
.cInputLarge {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <input class="cDefault" ng-class="fieldSize">
  <br>
  <br>{{fieldSize}}
</div>
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for you answer, it works! I will mark it as correct answer as soon as possible. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Yes its  correct .
You can bind to a scope variable

Comment: Hi, but look at my snippet... it's still 50px and not 200px from the binded class...?

Comment: I checked it is width: 200px;

Answer (score 0):

Or try this

```
   <input class="cDefault"  ng-class="{{'fieldSize'}}">
```